# level curve not tangent to the constraint curve

Tags: calculus, constraints

Is level curves always spread in one direction(monotonic increasing or decreasing)?
for example,
[image]
[image]

I change 3 to 6, I think it is possibile for a graph's level curve exists in this pattern. But obviously the level curve's gradient is not parallel to the constraint curve's gradient, but it has the biggest value which is 6.

Comment: The biggest problem would be that the underlying function $f(x,y)$ would no longer be continuous--if we went from a height of 4 to a height of 6, we would have necessarily crossed a contour line with a height of 5 by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Similarly, where should the vector gradient point along this contour line with a height of 6? It needs to indicate the direction of maximum increase.

Comment: @erfink then I can add one more level curve whose value is 5 again and placed betwwen 4 and 6

Comment: If we fix that problem by filling in the missing level curves so there are no jumps, then the graph of the function looks like a volcanic mountain with a crater blown out of the top. Along the edge of the crater will be the highest point (say, the level curve $f(x,y)=6$). Since this is a local maximum, the gradient vector at any point on this curve will be $\vec{0}$.

Comment: @erfink Thank u for your answer. I still don't quite get it and I don't want to go deeper.So can I just confirm that, the value of level curves are always increase or decrease in one direction, there will never be a value greatern or smaller than values of surrending level curves? Is this statement correct?

Comment: Here's a better way to state what I think you're after: there are no "jumps" as we travel between adjacent level curves. For example, {5,4,3,2} and {5,4,5,6,5,4,3,2} are allowed, but not {5,4,6,1,5}

Comment: @erfink sorry, just had a strange idea popped uo in my brain, if I add 5 between 4 and 6, and then add 4 and 3 between 6 and 2 in the second graph, 6 is still the largest value, which contradicts that 4 should be the largest value?

Comment: I think what you're describing is adding in levels curves as I suggested so there are no jumps. I'm assuming that you're looking at this in the context of Lagrange multipliers? This technique will pick up all possible extrema, not just one. In this hypothetical example, we would find that $\nabla g$ and $\nabla f$ are parallel at 4 places: where $g(x,y)=c$ is tangent to $f(x,y)=4$, the two points where it crosses $f(x,y)=6$, and where it is tangent to $f(x,y)=3$. The multiplier $\lambda$ will be positive, zero, and negative respectively. We then need  to determine which are min/max